# How do I batch copy existing file names and use them as new folder names?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, filenames

I have folders with several files. What I want to do is to use the filenames of those files as the names of folders that woud be created within the same directory:

[image: Screenshot of file names and folder name]

How can I get the string `data_1a` from `data_1a.txt` and automatically batch create a new folder using that name (like the `data_1a` folder)?

Comment: Superuser is not a free script writing service though, you should provide what you have tried already and show that you have already put research into what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
forfiles /M *.txt /C "cmd /c if not exist @fname\ md @fname"
```